# How can I amend my Payload to send multiple objects in one call (Endpoint: D365FO)?

Tags: postman, microsoft-dynamics, web-api-testing

I've currently got a JSON Payload designed for an OData API as follows:
{
"testData":"testData"
}

Wherein the above payload consists of one object that will be inserted into a D365 data entity. However, right now I need to do a form of testing in which I have to send multiple objects in one call, AKA my call should look something like this:

```
{"testData": "testData1"},
{"testData": "testData2"},
{"testData": "testData3"},
{"testData": "testData4"}
```

To do such testing, I need to find a way to modify my payload within PostMan; how could I do so?

Thanks!

Comment: ODatas Batch API looks promising for this but you might need to include more details in your post. 

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/all-in-one-with-odata-batch/
https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/

Certain services seem to use JSON to batch and some use Mime-Part so getting it into Postman will be different depending on your setup.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Sheena, OData Batch API works (: I've provided a link that explains how to amend OData batch for D365 Finance and Operations, which is the exact application that is supposed to serve as our endpoint. Thanks so much!